# How to write a gorm function for where clause with dynamic variables

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to create a sql query :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 10 AND name = "Chetan"
```

Now, gorm's where function looks like below,

```
// Where return a new relation, filter records with given conditions, accepts `map`, `struct` or `string` as conditions, refer http://jinzhu.github.io/gorm/crud.html#query
func (s *DB) Where(query interface{}, args ...interface{}) *DB {
    return s.clone().search.Where(query, args...).db
}
```

Which mean it accepts a query and args. Example :

```
dbDriver.Where("id = ?", id).First(t)
```

How do i dynamically pass multiple variables. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 10 AND name = "Chetan"
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 10
SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender = "male" AND name = "Chetan" AND age = "30"
```

Is it poosible to write a single gorm function for such dynamic SQL statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first param of `.Where()` accepts `string` and the rest is variadic, this means you have the capability to modify the query and the values.

In the below example, I've prepared `field1` & `field2`, and also `value1` & `value2` for representing the names of the fields I want to filter and their values respectively.

> The values can be in any type since it's `interface{}`.

```golang
var field1 string = "id"
var value1 interface{} = 10

var field2 string = "age"
var value2 interface{} = "30"

dbDriver.Where(field1 " = ? AND " + field2 + " = ?", value1, value2).First(t)
```

#### Update 1

> What if i am not sure what are number of parameter i will be passing? In this case we are hardcoding to two. What if that function/method passes 3 ?

One possible solution to achieve that, is by using slices to hold the criteria. You will have the control to dynamically adjust the `fields` and `values`.

```golang
fields := []string{"id = ?", "age = ?"}
values := []interface{}{10, "30"}

dbDriver.Where(strings.Join(fields, " AND "), values...).First(t)
```

#### Update 2

As per @Eklavya's comment, it's also possible to use a predefined struct object or a `map` instead of a `string` on the where clause.

```golang
db.Where(&User{Name: "jinzhu", Age: 20}).First(&user)
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = "jinzhu" AND age = 20 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;

db.Where(map[string]interface{}{"name": "jinzhu", "age": 20}).Find(&users)
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = "jinzhu" AND age = 20;
```

Reference: [GORM query reference](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map)

Comment: This makes sense.  I should have asked my question better. I have edited my question. What if i am not sure what are number of parameter i will be passing? In this case we are hardcoding to two. What if that function/method passes 3 ?

Comment: @Chetan my advice, read the doc about gorm. the `.Where()` method's scheme makes us really easy to apply a dynamic where clause. the first param is a string (easy to construct the query), the rest parameters are slices (we can pass any params there)

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `map[string]interface{}` for coditions in `.Where()`

```
m := make(map[string]interface{})
m["id"] = 10
m["name"] = "chetan"
db.Where(m).Find(&users)
```

Just add your conditions in map then send inside `where`.

Or you can use struct in `.Where()`. Create a variable of struct and set those field for which you want to query and send inside `where`

```
db.Where(&User{Name: "chetan", Gender: "Male"}).First(&user)
```

**NOTE**: When query with struct, GORM will only query with those fields has non-zero value, that means if your field’s value is 0, '', false or other zero values, it won’t be used to build query conditions.

Referrence: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map